# YouTube API - Play/Pause Toggle Button

Tags: jquery, api, youtube

I have an embedded YouTube video with a transparent PNG "frame" in front of it, so I need to have an invisible play/pause button in front of the PNG. Everything is working correctly, and the video plays onClick, BUT I can't pause the video once it's playing. I've tried several variations of "section 4" below, and nothing seems to work. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

```
    var video_id = $('#video-player').attr('data-id');
    // 1. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 2. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video', {
            width: '470',
            height: '263',
            videoId: 'ubvR6_pwpIk',
            playerVars: {
                modestbranding: 1,
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                wmode: 'opaque',
                branding: 0,
                autohide: 0,
                rel: 0
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    // 3. The API calls this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        $('#video-button').click(function(event){
            player.playVideo();
        });
    }

    // 4. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            $('#video-button').click(function(event){
                player.pauseVideo();
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#video-button').click(function(event){
                player.playVideo();
            });
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your condition here:

```
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
```

Try this instead:

```
var state = player.getPlayerState();
if(state==1){
```

Here is the state list:

- -1 : unstarted
- 0 : ended
- 1 : playing
- 2 : paused
- 3 : buffering
- 5 : video cued

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en#Playback_status)

**EDIT**
Since same result...

Try to console.log something in the `onPlayerStateChange`...
Just to see if it really fires.
I suggest you console.log the `state` variable I suggested above.
Also try to console.log the `event` to confirm it is there.

I would be surprised if these debugging test reveal nothing...

---
I just found this in the documentation:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
  alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

Comment: I think they're interchangeable - according to the iframe API reference:
Possible values are:
-1 (unstarted)
0 (ended)
1 (playing)
2 (paused)
3 (buffering)
5 (video cued).
...In your code, you can specify the integer values or you can use one of the following namespaced variables:
YT.PlayerState.ENDED
YT.PlayerState.PLAYING
YT.PlayerState.PAUSED
YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING
YT.PlayerState.CUED

I tried your code, but got the same results... Any other ideas? (Thanks for your help!)

Comment: I just made an edit... Check if something works in all this. ;)

Comment: Always check the console... Always check the console... Thank you. I assumed it was my code, but it wasn't. Chrome console errors led me down a path that pointed to the Chromecast extension. When I disabled the Chromecast extension, everything was working fine. (Checking in a different browser would also have helped, but again...I assumed the problem was me.) Thanks so much for helping with this -- I appreciate your time and expertise.